Django lookup values in table from array of keys in template
I have an SQLite DB with, among other things, a table with attribute_id and attribute_name. The attribute_id fields increase in 10 step increments as I may need to manually insert attributes without impacting the ids and order of existing attributes.
It currently has 186 attributes in it with ids from 10 to 1830. I don’t expect this table to ever grow beyond 200 attributes so it’s small and always will be. That may be important for performance purposes.
In another table in the same DB I have items, currently about 1000. This number will grow but I don’t expect it to ever grow beyond 100,000 items.
Every item in the table has a text field called attributes that holds an array with the attribute_id of one or more attributes. I don’t expect an item to ever have more than 10 attribute_ids in this field.
In a Django template I wish to show the attribute_name for each item in comma separated text while retaining the order of the attribute_ids in the array. That is where I’m stuck.
In a For Loop of potentially hundreds of records I currently pass the contents of {{ items.attributes }} to a Template Tag where I do the lookup to get the attribute_names belonging to the attribute_ids. The challenge is that these attribute_ids are passed as [“100”, “300”, “120”] from Template to the Template Tags operation but a lookup to find the corresponding values requires these numbers to be INTs. I can’t convert to INT if the string contains [ or ] or “. I’m currently trying to do some hacking by removing those chars from the string without any success.
Then I realised there must be a much smoother ways to do this. Any hints?
Or, am I making this all too complicated and should I just pass this small table once from the View and let the Template match them up in the For Loop without dipping into the Template Tags hundreds of times?

Why are attribute IDs passed as strings and not ints? In what circumstances could one of these strings contain a square bracket character?

@halfer The application was originally in PHP and it stored a JSON Array in that field. That's why it now returns ["420","550"], for instance.
It's being migrated to Django in steps. I could probably change the field in the DB to something else if that helps but it would require changing the whole DB input process too, not just the display.

OK, righto. So can't Django just JSON decode this field, so that it gets an array of strings? They would then be castable to ints, and no square brackets would get passed to a casting function.
